# Always install to "Program Files" (also on x64)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, setup-project

I am using a default Visual Studio Setup Project to create an installer for my application.
The application is built as "Any CPU" and runs as a 64bit process on x64 OSes, but the installer always uses "Program Files (x86)" as the default directory.

Is it possible to always use "Program Files" as the default so it is in the correct folder on a x64 OS?

Comment: How are you currently specifying the target location?

Comment: Currently I use '[ProgramFilesFolder]' which is mapped to 'Program Files (x86)' on x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only 64-bit packages can use Program Files on a 64-bit machine.

In Visual Studio setup projects the only solution is to use separate 32-bit and 64-bit packages. A 32-bit package for 32-bit systems and a 64-bit package for 64-bit systems.

Some commercial setup authoring tools (for example Advanced Installer or InstallShield) allow you to create mixed 32/64-bit packages which automatically adapt to the target platform (32-bit or 64-bit).

But [do you really need a 64-bit package](http://setupanddeployment.com/installation-environment/32bit-64bit-installers/)?

Comment: I don't believe that's true. What you say is true for folders subject to the file system redirector, but that is not the case for program files.

Comment: Note that your 64-bit installer doesn't *have* to install a 64-bit application, the msi just needs to be marked 64-bit and the MSI [ProgramFiles] folder will be correctly pointed.